# How can I Seed data from a SQL file?

Tags: sql, database, linq, seed, sample-data

I have a database connected to a MVC 4 Project.
The Database is creating automatically from this code:

```
public class ContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ContextModel>
{
    protected override void Seed(ContextModel context)
    {
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

I saw that people Seed back the database after drop and recreate with this code:

```
 System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new CarStore.Models.SampleData.cs);
```

This works grate. But my question is:

1st. How can I seed data from a SQL file, i have that SampleData.sql, and how can I 'run' that file to insert back all the data.

and 2nd is there a way to make BackUp to latest version from your database data, before you DropAndCreateIfModelChanges ?
And then to seed that data back from that file ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I GOT THE ANSWER :)

I finally manage to solve this problem.

Here is the code, maybe someone needs it !

```
var baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(File.ReadAllText(baseDirectory + 
"\\IF YOU HAVE ANOTHER DIRECTOR INSIDE BASEDIR \\SQL" + "\\YOURFILENAME.sql"));
```

It works for me very good and fast.
It's optimized and readable.